# Which curios can have an item used on them for a greater effect?

Tags: darkest-dungeon

I know there are some curios (interact-able objects) that you can use items on in order to give a positive effect. For example using a skeleton key on large chests for additional loot and using holy water on some altars for a boon. But I've tried holy water on some other types of religious looking curios and they have had no effect. I'm also curious if there are other interactions that use the other items like the herbal medicine, antivenom or bandages.

**What are all the curios that can you can use an item on in order to get a positive outcome?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got everything you need to know about curio on this [wiki](http://darkestdungeon.gamepedia.com/Curio#List_of_Curios).

As you suspected, there is a lot of curio which you can apply item on to be sure to have a positive effect.

There is also some which can give you negative effect depending of the item used but they're is few of them compare to the good combinations.

*Note : It's up to date with the Crimson Court DLC.*